# Syntax to alter and create composite foreign key in postgres

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, alter-table, composite-primary-key

I have a table in Postgres with a composite primary key.

What's the syntax to alter another existing table to add a composite foreign key to the composite primary key of the first table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE my_fk_table
ADD CONSTRAINT my_fk 
FOREIGN KEY (pk1, pk2) 
REFERENCES my_pk_table
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```